# Redirect with a port

Tags: dns, tcp, minecraft

We want to launch a little Minecraft server community, With one server for a forum, another for the Minecraft server.

I know how to make a subdomain for the MC server but what I want is to have the same domain for server and forum. If player enter domain.tld in Minecraft client, how to make him redirect automatically to the second server?

Comment: You would need to run the two services on different ports.  You would forward traffic on those ports, to the same address, UCP/TCP would handle the rest.

Answer (score 1):

Minecraft supports DNS SRV records for server lookup. When you try to connect to `example.com`, it will first look for a **SRV record at `_minecraft._tcp.example.com`** before falling back to the usual direct A/AAAA lookup. SRV also lets you add the port number so that clients won't need to enter one.

Depending on how your DNS domain manager works, you might have to enter the service name as `minecraft` (with or without the underscore), and select TCP as the protocol. Priority and weight can be 0 (the values are only important if the same SRV record has multiple servers).

Note that SRV records must point to another (regular) domain name, *not* an IP address.